# Hbase Python Filter based on the row key

Tags: python, filter, hbase

I'm using Python and Hbase and I need to filter rows from Hbase based on the row key.

I managed to make it work for a column `title:t`, but I couldn't find any way to apply the substring filter to the row key column.

Here is how I did it for `title:t` column and it works fine:

```
for key, data in index.scan(filter="SingleColumnValueFilter('title','t',=,'substring:Valera')"):
```

And here is how I'm doing for the row key:

```
for key, data in index.scan(filter="SingleColumnValueFilter('cf','id',=,'substring:Valera')"):
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Just properly align your question.

Comment: the python module you used is happybase ?

Answer (score 1):

**Use `RowFilter` if you want to filter by row key** :

```
for key, data in index.scan(filter="RowFilter(=,'substring:Valera')"):
    print key, data
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Your answer saved several hours of my life! :)